# Not sure what this question is asking about.

Tags: mathematical-physics

My lecturer ask me to answer this question but i can't seem to find any explanation on google after searching for quite some time.

[image]

Comment: This question looks more like physics....

Comment: Change the tag , Thanks

Comment: What happens as $t$ gets larger? If you still can't answer then, then maybe look transient up in a dictionary.

Comment: I think about it . Thanks

Comment: Setting C=2, R=3 and w=5, I get a sine wave for the steady state, and in engineering terms (process dynamics and control), a first order system for the transient.

Comment: I search for more info on it as i never learn anything on process, dynamics and control. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your circuit is driven with a sinusoidal input, then the steady-state response will be some form of a sinusoid. However, while the system is still adjusting to the new input (think, a car driving over a pot hole), its response will have certain characteristics (bouncing up and down for a while) that do not last indefinitely. These characteristics are called the transient response, whereas the response characteristics that last indefinitely (for the duration of the steady input) are called the steady-state response.

Comment: I can understand a little about what your trying to say but i cant seem find a answer to the question.

Comment: Notice that that the steady state component of the voltage will never go to zero as time progresses (lim t-> inf V_steadystate =...). Whereas the transient component will go to zero (lim t-> inf V_transient = 0). Thus, since it decays away, it must be the transient component of the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

In steady state, it is oscillatory in this case and stays on forever, or until you switch the power off:

It is of the form $ A  cos(... t)  +B sin(... t) $

*Transient* means it is going to stay on only for a short time like the exponential decay
as in this case:

$C e^{(-...t)} $

(...) is some constant.